# Garage door effect: hide content beneath before it rises

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to have a garage door effect where when the site is loaded you see a garage door. ON hover, the door lifts and the content is behind it. The problem I have is getting my content to remain hidden until the door lifts. Any ideas would be appreciated. Have a look at the site: http://vcube.netau.net/

If code is needed, I can supply that to.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <img src="./images/Logo_door.png" class="top">

        <section id="main">
        <!-- main content here -->
        </section>

        <footer id="footer">
        <!-- where video and map will go -->
            <div id="video">
                <iframe class="hidden" width="363" height="187" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Pd00CAw15-E?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="map">
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>  
</div>
```

And here ist he CSS

```
body {
    background:url('../images/background1.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-y repeat-x;
    }

#wrapper {
    background:url('../images/background2.gif');
    display:block;
    height:600px;
    width:900px;
    padding:10px 0 10px 0;
    margin:auto;
    border-radius:15px;
    }

footer {
    margin:auto;
    width:800px;
    height:200px;
    }

#main {
    height:350px;
    margin:0px 50px 50px 50px;
    width:800px;
    border-radius:15px;
    padding:0;
    -moz-box-shadow:  inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px#888;
    box-shadow:  inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    }

#video {
    background:black;
    padding:0;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 25px;
    float:right;
    width:375px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-box-shadow:  inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px#888;
    box-shadow:  inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    }

#video iframe {
    margin:6px 0 0 6px;
    }

#map {
    padding:0;
    margin:0px 25px 0px 0px;
    border-radius:10px;
    float:left;
    width:375px;
    height: 200px;
    -moz-box-shadow:  inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px#888;
    box-shadow:  inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    }

.top {
    margin:auto;
    height:700px;
    width:900px;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    }
```

And the jquery i'm using.

```
$(function() {

    $('#wrapper').hover(function() {
    $('img.top', $(this)).stop().animate({top: '-900px'}, 1000); 
        },function() {
    $('img.top', $(this)).stop().animate({top: '10px'}, 1000);
    })
});
```

Comment: Have you tried any implementation? Some code please?

Comment: You code will help a lot sir, cause then we would be able to mess around with and tell you where exactly your code should be altered.
But what you should probably do is have you text star as hidden then call a call back function to show it once you the animation is complete. PS you have a problem with Z-index and flash, you should have a look at this http://www.scorchsoft.com/news/youtube-z-index-embed-iframe-fix

Comment: Sorry, I added the code above. This is my first post as I usually search until I can find the answer.

Comment: ACtually, Marwan Doumit may have figured it out for me. After applying the fix for embeded youtube and applying a z-index, it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial opacity to `opacity: 0` for the content you want to be hidden in the initial page load and then change it to `opacity: 1` when `document.ready` or `window.ready` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I don't like giving one sentence answers... http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that as an easier method.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is the the code that will make your main appear when the animation is complete

Jquery part

```
  $(function() {

    $('#wrapper').hover(function() {
    $('img.top', $(this)).stop().animate({top: '-900px'}, 1000 , function(){$('.hidden').css('display' , 'block');}); 
        },function() {
        $('.hidden').css('display' , 'none');
    $('img.top', $(this)).stop().animate({top: '10px'}, 1000);
    })
});
```

Css part

```
body {
    background:url('../images/background1.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-y repeat-x;
    }

#wrapper {
    background:url('../images/background2.gif');
    display:block;
    height:600px;
    width:900px;
    padding:10px 0 10px 0;
    margin:auto;
    border-radius:15px;
    }

footer {
    margin:auto;
    width:800px;
    height:200px;
    }

#main {
    height:350px;
    margin:0px 50px 50px 50px;
    width:800px;
    border-radius:15px;
    padding:0;
    -moz-box-shadow:  inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px#888;
    box-shadow:  inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    }

#video {
    background:black;
    padding:0;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 25px;
    float:right;
    width:375px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-box-shadow:  inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px#888;
    box-shadow:  inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    }

#video iframe {
    margin:6px 0 0 6px;
    }

#map {
    padding:0;
    margin:0px 25px 0px 0px;
    border-radius:10px;
    float:left;
    width:375px;
    height: 200px;
    -moz-box-shadow:  inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px#888;
    box-shadow:  inset 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    }

.top {
    margin:auto;
    height:700px;
    width:900px;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    }
.hidden{
    display : none;
}
```

And HTML part i also fixed your embed here

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <img src="./images/Logo_door.png" class="top">

        <section id="main" class="hidden">
        <!-- main content here -->
        </section>

        <footer id="footer" class="hidden">
        <!-- where video and map will go -->
            <div id="video">
                <iframe class="hidden" width="363" height="187" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Pd00CAw15-E?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="map">
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>  
</div>
```